# Executing AsyncTask in onCreateView doesn't display information on 1st attempt

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am in the process of creating a recipe app on Android. The user can add recipes to his favourites list (which I store in my database via webservices) and he should be able to view the favourites list with the recipes he has favourited.

I am using an AsyncTask to fetch all recipes from the database, this uses SharedPreferences to keep track of the username, which is passed as a parameter to my webservices to get recipes for that username.

The favourites page is an option via the NavigationDrawer, once clicked it should execute the AsyncTask and immediately populate the favourites list with the recipe information. But when I access the favourites page the first time, I get a success return from the terminal, however the page is blank. When I access the favourites list on the second attempt, the page successfully loads with the recipe information. I have tried many different combinations like executing the task before inflating the Fragment, tried executing it on NavigationDrawerItem click but that gives me an error.

How can I make this display on the first attempt? I am sure I am missing something so obvious but I can't see it!

**1st attempt**

[image]

**2nd attempt**

[image]

**Favourites.java**

```
public static Favourites newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        Favourites fragment = new Favourites();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        session = new SessionManager(getActivity());

        if(!session.isLoggedIn()){
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container, new Login());
            ft.commit();
        }

        new DisplayFavourite().execute();

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favs, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        final ListView myListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.favouritesView);
        lazyFavsAdapter = new LazyFavsAdapter(getActivity(),Favourites.pairs);
        myListView.setAdapter(lazyFavsAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
```

**DisplayFavourite**

```
  class DisplayFavourite extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String user_id;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Retrieving Favourites...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

        user_id = session.getID();

    }

    /**
     * Fetching Favourited recipes
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Building Parameters
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("user_id", user_id);

        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("MyWebsiteURL",
                "POST", params);

        // check for success tag
        try {
            JSONArray array  = json.getJSONArray("results");
            //Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            if (pairs.size()>0){
                pairs.clear();
            }

            if (array.length() > 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++){
                    set = new HashMap<>();
                    JSONObject jo = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    image = jo.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
                    name = jo.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    recipe_id = jo.getString(TAG_ID);
                    rating = jo.getString(TAG_RATING);
                    source = jo.getString(TAG_SOURCE);

                    set.put("image", image);
                    set.put("name", name);
                    set.put("recipe_id", recipe_id);
                    set.put("rating", rating);
                    set.put("source", source);
                    pairs.add(set);

                }

            } else {
        //      Log.d("Failure!",json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
        //      return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();

        //print recipes to terminal
        for(int j =0; j<pairs.size(); j++) {
            System.out.println(pairs.get(j));

        }
    }

}
```

**LazyFavsAdapter.java**

```
public class LazyFavsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

public LazyFavsAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    TextView nameText=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.recipe_name);
    nameText.setText(Favourites.pairs.get(position).get("name"));

    TextView sourceText=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.source);
    sourceText.setText(Favourites.pairs.get(position).get("source"));

    RatingBar ratingBar =(RatingBar)vi.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(Favourites.pairs.get(position).get("rating")));

    ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.recipe_pic);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(Favourites.pairs.get(position).get("image"), image);
    return vi;

    }
}
```

**MainPage.java**

```
@Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (position == 0) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(1))
                    .commit();

        } else if (position == 1) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, Search.newInstance(2))
                    .commit();

        }

        else if (position == 2) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, Favourites.newInstance(3))
                    .commit();
        }

        else if (position == 3) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, AccountManagement.newInstance(4))
                    .commit();

        }

    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

N.B. I know I'll probably get slaughtered for poor coding standards but I'll sort it out later!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might need a lazyFavsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in your onPostExecute.